# Issue on building flutter apk with flutter_tts dependency

Tags: android, flutter, class, flutter-dependencies, program-entry-point

I was building a flutter app in a Windows machine and I stopped working on it for several months, after that I now get issues on running the app. It shows those two errors:

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\okeyr\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\flutter_tts-3.6.3\android\build.gradle' line: 31
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':flutter_tts'.

> org/gradle/api/services/BuildService

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Program Files\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 463
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_tts'.

> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Cannot invoke method substring() on null object
> compileSdkVersion is not specified.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Flutter doctor shows everything fine except:

[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components

But I don't think the issue is related with that.

I've I look in depth at failure number 1. I have check the file that gives the error and I found that in line 31:

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

So I just went to the file and deleted all the entries related with kotlin, because I am not using Kotlin (I guess).

Then if I rerun the app it now shows another error (related with tts again), but doesn't show the previous ones (not sure if I've moved forward or backwards)

Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
C:\Users\okeyr\AndroidStudioProjects\fluttertestapp\android\app\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.tundralabs.fluttertts.FlutterTtsPlugin());
^
symbol:   class FlutterTtsPlugin
location: package com.tundralabs.fluttertts
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 16s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

After doing a search I found many people with that similar issue (even though none was related to tts plugin) which had adressed it with a flutter pub cache repair or a flutter clean. However, a flutter clean gives me no changes and error persists and when I have executed flutter pub cache repair it had shown:

Failed to repair flutter_tts 3.6.3. Error:
Pub failed to delete entry because it was in use by another process.
This may be caused by a virus scanner or having a file
in the directory open in another application.
Reinstalled 29 packages.
Failed to reinstall 1 package:

- flutter_tts 3.6.3
  pub finished with exit code 69

Now, if I rerun the code it gives me new error:

The plugin `flutter_tts` doesn't have a main class defined in C:\Users\okeyr\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\flutter_tts-3.6.3\android\src\main\java\com\tundralabs\fluttertts\FlutterTtsPlugin.java or C:\Users\okeyr\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\flutter_tts-3.6.3\android\src\main\kotlin\com\tundralabs\fluttertts\FlutterTtsPlugin.kt. This is likely to due to an incorrect `androidPackage: com.tundralabs.fluttertts` or `mainClass` entry in the plugin's pubspec.yaml.
If you are the author of this plugin, fix the `androidPackage` entry or move the main class to any of locations used above. Otherwise, please contact the author of this plugin and consider using a different plugin in the meanwhile.

This error also appears when running pub get or pug upgrade. But if I run pub outdated it gives me that:

Showing outdated packages.
[*] indicates versions that are not the latest available.

Package Name  Current   Upgradable  Resolvable  Latest

direct dependencies: all up-to-date.

transitive dependencies:
characters    *1.2.1    *1.2.1      *1.2.1      1.3.0
collection    *1.17.0   *1.17.0     *1.17.0     1.17.1
js            *0.6.5    *0.6.5      *0.6.5      0.6.7
meta          *1.8.0    *1.8.0      *1.8.0      1.9.0
path          *1.8.2    *1.8.2      *1.8.2      1.8.3

transitive dev_dependencies:
matcher       *0.12.13  *0.12.13    *0.12.13    0.12.14
test_api      *0.4.16   *0.4.16     *0.4.16     0.4.18
all dependencies are up-to-date.
Process finished with exit code 0

I can't see any dependency related with tts.

Now here I am stucked in that error, I don't know how to proceed. If there is someone who could help me see the light I'd be grateful. Thanks in advance.

I am trying to run the code but it seems tts package is not well defined, anyone that could bring me some help?

Comment: I just decided to remove flutter_tts dependency, comment the code related to flutter_tts and reimplement it using another package called text_to_speech, when I run it I get again the 2 failures I got in the beginning but now for the text_to_speech package. May I be doing something wrong on using packages? May be anything wrong on my project configuration that trigger that issue? Is there any general issue related with text_to_speech in flutter?

Comment: I tried installing other package not related with tts and issue is gone. Then I tried installing a package called speech_to_text (instead of text_to_speech) and it also shows the 2 failure error when app runs. I remove/add the dependencies with flutter pub add/remove and no error is shown in any of the cases (tts, text_to_speech, speech_to_text) but the problem comes when running the app if any of those dependencies are added on the pub (it doesn't matter if I am using them or not in the code). May be it related with the factory package they are using: org/gradle/api/services/BuildService?